# Wait for Cloud Firestore task result

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to develop a method to access the Cloud Firestore, read a user's data and return the map associated to it. For what I understand, it is not waiting for the success/failure listener, and I already tried changing it for a complete listener but the result is the same. It skips through the listeners.
I know that this is a Assynchronous process, but I need to receive the data to show them on the Activity that calls the method.

Settings Activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.binding = ActivitySettingsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        this.fbUtils = new FirebaseHandler(this);
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        User user = fbUtils.getCurrentUser();
        if (user == null) {
            findUserOrLogout();
        } else {
            showUserData(user);
        }
    }
```

FirebaseHandler

```
    public User getCurrentUser() {
        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            this.userMap = getUserDBInfo(user.getUid());
            this.profilePic = getUserPic(user.getUid());
            if (this.userMap != null && this.profilePic != null) {
                return new User(user, userMap, profilePic);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    private Map<String, Object> getUserDBInfo(String uid) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Getting user info for user '" + uid+"'");
        DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document(uid);
        final Map<String, Object>[] userMap = new Map[]{null};
        final boolean[] done = new boolean[]{false};
        docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DocShot: " + documentSnapshot);
                    userMap[0] = documentSnapshot.getData();
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User's document not found");
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Couldn't get the Document");
                MainActivity.showToast("Couldn't get the Document", activity.getApplicationContext());
            }
        });
        return userMap[0];
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong in my code, or is there anything I can change to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your code is skipping the listener completely then please check the rules in Firebase, and set them to `public`.

Comment: maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value)

Comment: I've tried with the callback. Same result. @YogeshSingh what did you mean with the rules in Firebase? This?

`
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth!=null;
    }
  }
}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the rules inside the Firebase console to allow a write operation.

You've to follow the steps given below to do so:-

1. Open your Firebase Console and navigate to Database.
2. There go to the **Rules** tab and edit the rules to following:-

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

This will allow you to perform write operations on your DB.

Please let me know if you will need screenshots.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply. Aren't those rules for Realtime? From what I've seen in this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules), it appears to be. Besides I've been able to access the database previously, so I don't think the problem is in the database

Comment: Yes, these rules are for Realtime. But as per your last comment on the question, you mentioned some rules, right. So, I think changing the `allow read, write: if request.auth!=null;` to `allow read, allow write;` will solve your issue. Actually I'm certain that it has to do something with the DB because I've faced the same issue, and changing the rules worked for me. Moreover, your code looks fine to me.

Comment: I've changed the rules, but the onsuccess/failure listener keeps not getting called. I'm lost. I have a code that does something similar in another activity, with the difference that the code itself is in the onstart method, and it works. I was trying to make it in another class this time to avoid repeting code, and when it would work, I would adapt the other activity to use it

Comment: Then, I think you should probably move the code into the `onStart()` method.

Comment: It worked. Why it doesn't outside the onstart I don't know. Guess I have to repeat code... Thanks for your time tho.

Comment: Relaxing security rules to allow **anyone with an internet connection to fully read and write the database** is not a good solution.  If the database should be locked down to only authenticated users, these rules do not enforce that at all.  The app should instead make sure that the user is fully signed in before making any requests.

Comment: Yes, but while in production state we've to turn the rules to fully read and write or else we can specify it to provide write operation to a particular user by passing in the id for that user.

Answer (score 0):

If your database requires an authenticated user to read and write the database then do use the other answer here.  It will create a massive security hole that allows for anyone with an internet connection to fully read and write the database.

Your code should instead ensure that a user is signed in before trying to make any queries.  This made possible by using an [auth state listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#addAuthStateListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)) to get a callback when the user is signed in.  Only after this callback is invoked with a valid user object is it safe to make a query that requires authentication.